# OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit not working when game is built

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I hover over a button (the button changes position on hover) in the Editor Player, OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit work. When I build the game and go and hover over the button it doesn't work. I've enabled Raycast Target and I have no idea how to fix this.

here is the code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardUp : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private Vector2 normalPos;
    
    void Start()
    {
        normalPos = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;

    }
    
    

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        LeanTween.move(gameObject, new Vector2(normalPos.x, normalPos.y + 150), 0.3f);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        LeanTween.move(gameObject, new Vector2(normalPos.x, normalPos.y), 0.3f);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Check that you didn't set Object's tag "editor only".
Try using event trigger component. It might solve your problem.

I wanted to comment this but I can't since not enough reputation, so I had to write this as an answer

Comment: I have tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have event system component in your scene? Make sure it has all the components. Also try creating another project and redoing what you did. Then see if that works. This sometimes helps to track down the issue and sometimes even solves my problems. Good luck

Comment: I fixed it, turns out I forgot to update my addressables

Comment: Congratulations